# Python, TOR, Requests - 'module' object has no attribute 'inet_pton'

Tags: python, tor

I am trying to make a GET request over TOR which is listening on 127.0.0.1:9050

I've installed request socks: pip install -U requests[socks]

```
 import requests
 tor_proxy = {'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050', 'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}

 r = requests.get("http://www.google.com", proxies=tor_proxy, timeout=20)
```

Here is the error from when I run the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    r = requests.get("http://www.google.com", proxies=tor_proxy, timeout=20)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 71, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 57, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 403, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 578, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 362, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1057, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1097, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 897, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 859, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 167, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\socks.py", line 81, in _new_conn
    **extra_kw
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 195, in create_connection
    sock.connect((remote_host, remote_port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 747, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 419, in _negotiate_SOCKS5
    CONNECT, dest_addr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 482, in _SOCKS5_request
    resolved = self._write_SOCKS5_address(dst, writer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 517, in _write_SOCKS5_address
    addr_bytes = socket.inet_pton(family, host)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'inet_pton'
```

Jun 11 13:13:55.000 [notice] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:0. Giving up. (waiting for socks info)

Thanks

Comment: What package did you installed exactly?

Comment: Please post the complete traceback

Comment: Thanks added traceback

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the library itself, in particular  PySocks [socks.py](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks/blob/master/socks.py#L517), [inet_pton](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_pton) is only available on unix:

**socket.inet_pton(address_family, ip_string)**

*Convert an IP address from its family-specific string format to a packed, binary format. inet_pton() is useful when a library or network protocol calls for an object of type struct in_addr (similar to inet_aton()) or struct in6_addr.*

*Supported values for address_family are currently AF_INET and AF_INET6. If the IP address string ip_string is invalid, socket.error will be raised. Note that exactly what is valid depends on both the value of address_family and the underlying implementation of inet_pton().*

**Availability: Unix (maybe not all platforms).**

One workaround is to install [win_inet_pton](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_inet_pton) and import it in your script, the method will automatically be added to the socket lib.